# CSV to HTML TABLE jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, csv

I'm using this awesome jquery.csvtotable.js plugin to convert my csv to html tables. My question is, How do I make it where I can select the .csv from a browse button that is not server side control ?

```
 <div id="CSVTable"></div>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               $(function () {
                   $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('test.csv');
               });
           </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [read your csv file using javascript and html5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and try to use the base64 data with CSVToTable.

Or you could upload the csv file to the server (Using a hidden iframe to simulate ajax) and using the returned file url with CSVToTable.

Comment: the file api is not supported  by browser. I need it to be browser friendly :(.

Comment: Simply ask the user to copy-paste the csv content into a textarea.

Comment: Etienne thank you for taking the time to try to answer my question. What do you mean "copy-paste the csv content into a text area" ?

Comment: You can use the prompt() function or something similar to ask the user to [copy and paste](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCut%2C_copy%2C_and_paste&ei=tvK_VKnGEcPXggSvg4TQAg&usg=AFQjCNFfeagtiX5P6oxfMUPgc2kQEiYb2w&bvm=bv.84116906,d.eXY) the content of the csv file, but it may be too complicated since you want the thing to be friendly.